# jQuery .each() to add event handler

Tags: jquery, json, iteration, each

I'm having an issue with the .each() function in jQuery, I'm calling these lines when I successfully getAjax and store it in the data variable:

```
$.each(data, function() {
$('#modulesList').append("<p><a href='#'>" + this.code + "</a></p>")
  .click(function(){
    alert($(this));
   });
});
```

The problem is, Once I click on one of my a elements(Which all look fine and have the correct text) I get the alert popping up 5 times for each of them. Iterating from the 0 to 5 objects in the JSON.

Anybody know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `appendTo` method

```
$("<p><a href='#'>" + this.code + "</a></p>").appendTo('#modulesList')
  .click(function(){
    alert($(this));
   })
```

jQuery ~ always returns the main element: now you selector is a dom element and this gets created and returned as a jQuery Object.

And to answer you question of why you get 5 alerts . Before you bound the click event to `#modulesList` one for each object in the data array. (Thats why the 5 alerts)

You can also store your `<p><a>...` in a variable like so:

```
var pAndATag = $("<p><a href='#'>" + this.code + "</a></p>");
$(modulesList).append(pAndATag);
```

hope you see how this works...

Comment: Thanks for your help AndreasAL I figured out this morning why It was appearing 5 times but still didn't know how to fix it, It's working fine now!

Answer (score 3):

Mabey try this instead

```
$.each(data, function() {
$('#modulesList').append("<p><a href='#'>" + this.code + "</a></p>");

});

$('#modulesList p').click(function(){
    alert($(this));
   });
```

Comment: While this offers the desired functionality, @AndreasAL's solution is better because it doesn't make jQuery re-find the appended elements.